# How to import a customer static library into Objective C project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created a static library using Objective - C and generates a library called: libDummy.a, with header called ClassOne.h and ClassOne.m, then I need to add this library into another project, but it keeps reporting "libDummy/ClassOne.h" cannot be found.

And I have copied the libDummy.a to the same folder as the new project, also I checked the Search Library path, it's pointing to the correct folder, but the problem still exists.

Any idea about how to fix that?

Comment: Check it is reporting under tests folder..error. If it is the case as iOSNob said below click the check box for App.tests also while adding the library to new project..!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

1) Remove all the files and re-add them to project bundle, but dont forget to select as shown in below image,
[image: Select all the targets]

2) Recheck library path again and add.

Answer (score 0):

Link the library file in build Phases

Xcode->Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries

Add your .a file here.